# Динамическое добавление элементов на форме

Tags: asp.net-webforms

Хотел создать кнопку которая будет добавлять элементы на форму
но столкнулся с проблемой каждый раз нажимая на кнопку затираются предыдущие элементы
мой код

```
protected void AddOrderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int orderCount = int.Parse(ProductCount.Value);
        PlaceHolder ProductPlaceHolder = new PlaceHolder();
        ProductPlaceHolder.ID = "ProductPlaceHolder" + ProductCount.Value;

        Label productLabel = new Label();
        DropDownList productDropDown = new DropDownList();

        productLabel.Text = "Product";
        productDropDown.ID = "ProductDropDown" + ProductCount.Value;

        Label productNumberLabel = new Label();
        TextBox productNumberTextBox = new TextBox();

        productNumberTextBox.ID = "ProductNumberTextBox" + ProductCount.Value;
        productNumberLabel.Text = "Product Number";

        ProductPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(productLabel);
        ProductPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(productDropDown);
        ProductPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(productNumberLabel);
        ProductPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(productNumberTextBox);

        ProductPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        Panel1.Controls.Add(ProductPlaceHolder);
        orderCount++;
        ProductCount.Value = orderCount.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Кажется я понял в чем проблема. каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку страница перезагружается и все динамически добавленные элементы удаляются, попробую исправить это с использованием Ajax